# Run out of disk space although I have only 1 program

Tags: release-hera

over the last months I have used this laptop only to play Dota 2. Thats the only videogame this computer has. This computer has over 200GB space but it says to me periodically that it is running out of space with less than 1GB. I dont understand what is taking up so much space, when I revise it on the File Manager it only shows me icons of files with locks on the corner. I can open them but I dont understand how to find or even if im supposed to delete any of this to make space. If I could reset the operating system I would have no problem cause I only have the game here but apparently my only option is to reinstall the OS according to the internet. I would love some help to fix my problem, thanks!

Comment: Start by running the 'df' command in terminal to see disk usage.

Comment: You could also use "Gnome disk analyzer" to check what is using a lot of space if you don't want to use the terminal.